# Use of SMOTE with training, test and dev sets

Tags: smote

I have a dataset with class imbalance about (1:10). I applied a SMOTE method by slitting  the dataset into training and dev.

I over sampled the training set using a SMOTE method and divided this set into training and test to  build a RF classifier.

When I evaluate the RF classifier on the dev set which has not be over sampled it preforms quite poorly.

Is it standard that I would apply SMOTE to the dev set as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving your subsets bad names, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets) fer reference.

By the way, NO, of course not, you should only apply SMOTE on training data, your goal is to train a model that predicts well real data, not synthetic ones, SMOTE is just an escamotage for achieving better training.

Answer (score 0):

See the advice on this topic here: 
https://beckernick.github.io/oversampling-modeling/